# Why does calling publishProgress inside a loop, and calling it a number of times (without a loop), show different behavior?

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask, progress-bar, android-progressbar

I am using [this library](https://github.com/navasmdc/MaterialDesignLibrary) to display a ProgressBar in the Activity's UI from the `onProgressUpdate` method of an `AsyncTask`.

So I wrote an SSCCE for this. **The problem is that** inside `doInBackground()` when I call `Thread.sleep(60)` in a loop iterating 100 times and call `publishProgress(i)` in each iteration, I can see the `DeterminateProgressBar` filling with color sequentially (sort of animating to show color as it progresses), as shown as follows

```
@Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
        progressBarDeterminate.setProgress(values[0]);
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... voidArgs) {
        ((MainActivity) context).runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                Toast.makeText(context, "doInBackground of MyTask called", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        for(int i = 0; i <= 100; i++){
            try {
                //publishProgress(i);
                Thread.sleep(60);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            publishProgress(i);
        }
}
```

**BUT when I leave the loop and just call `Thread.sleep(60)`, then `publishProgress(30)`, then `Thread.sleep(60)`, then `publishProgress(60)`,  then `Thread.sleep(60)` and then `publishProgress(100)`, I don't see the `ProgressBar` sequentially progressing**, instead it just fills with colors just in one step by the end of `doInBackground`.

```
@Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
        progressBarDeterminate.setProgress(values[0]);
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... voidArgs) {
        ((MainActivity) context).runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                Toast.makeText(context, "doInBackground of MyTask called", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        try {
            Thread.sleep(60);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        publishProgress(30);

        try {
            Thread.sleep(60);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        publishProgress(60);
        try {
            Thread.sleep(60);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        publishProgress(100);
        return "doInBackground of MyTask returning.";
    }
```

**The second way is more suitable for my app. So the question is why! and how do I fix this?**

Comment: in `onProgressUpdate` try to `Log.d` values[0], what do you see?

Answer (score 2):

The method `setProgress(int);` doesn't update smoothly the progress bar.
If you maximum is 100, when you set the progress to 30 it will directly show the progress filled at 30%.

In your first code sample, it looks smooth because you had 1 very 60 ms.

You should add more steps or use a true value of progress (% of download for example).